# Best Gear Shifters

Tags: gears, shifter

I am new to Bicycling. I have a question on gear shifters. Mostly the bikes are available with Revo Shifter and EF Fire Shifters. Which one of these are best and why it is?

Comment: Product recommendation questions are generally a poor fit for a Q&A site since the answers quickly become out of date. There are a number of previous posts that will help you know what to look for when buying a new/first [road](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/7979/213) [bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/what-makes-a-good-entry-level-road-bike), [commuter](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/23282/213) [bike](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/15696/213) and [mountain](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/6238/213) [bike](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/5745/213).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no best. It is purely preference.

Most high-end bicycles are equipped with the rapid fire levers - but this may be purely down to market consensus ie. what sells a bike.

Some XC racers still use the gripshift shifters and SRAM still make the high-end shifters.

I used gripshift years ago on my first mountain bikes but found them quite fragile in a crash.

Gripshift - you can change a whole stack of gears in a single twist. Rapid fire requires multiple few clicks to achieve the same movement. But this has not been a problem for myself in practice - if you read the terrain ahead.

The rapid fire levers are more robust and I am yet to break one.

Comment: I prefer the Shimano 18-speed (2 up front, 9 in back, with rocker bar to get up to 1-1) *out of prodxn* but **shim** will build it custom for you. The Townie 2011 2100d had this derailleur combo. good stuff. buyer beware--rear derailleurs break EZ.

Comment: @Tapper7 What's a rocker bar? Google isn't helping me, except a bunch of Chinese patents in, well, some combination of patent-speak and broken English.

Comment: The rocker bar helps the rear derailleur bump up to a super-low gear. That's just what I call it. I'm sure Shimano has a more technical term. Since the trend is now to have 1 gear up front and multiple in back, the lowest one often has a significantly larger diameter  (and diameter-differential) than all the others.