# Choice of two Stevens bikes, which one makes more sense?

Tags: shopping

I'm going to need a new bike for next summer, my local shop carries and suggested Stevens. I've sort of narrowed down my selection to two, but since there is a steep price difference I'm not particularly happy about taking advice from the people I'm about to buy it from.

I'm looking at `7X LITE DISC` vs. `8X SX DISC RACE`, [see comparison chart for comprehensive differences](http://www.stevensbikes.de/2016/index.php?compare=1&lang=en_US&cou=AT&left_bik_id=1041&right_bik_id=101).

The main difference seems to be a fixed vs. a suspension front fork (I don't do a lot of off-road biking, I'm mostly on tarmac or grit, albeit steep roads), however I don't know whether all the other differences are significant. Is the 650 Euro price difference warranted?

Comment: We don't do specific product recommendations on this SE stack - these bikes will not be available in a year.  However since you're new, I will point out your own statement "I don't do a lot of off-road biking" and ask "why do you need a suspension bike at all?"   so suggest the rigid fork.   Vote to delete as off topic.  Do read the SE tour at http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour for more understanding on how SE is different to most forums.

Comment: Product recommendation questions are generally a poor fit for a Q&A site since the answers quickly become out of date. There are a number of previous posts that will help you know what to look for when buying a new/first [road](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/7979/213) [bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/what-makes-a-good-entry-level-road-bike), [commuter](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/23282/213) [bike](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/15696/213) and [mountain](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/6238/213) [bike](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/5745/213).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you noticed yourself, the largest difference is suspension fork. It adds complexity and usually weight, but these bikes are almost same weight. That means that the one with suspension fork has lighter and more expensive components. Whether it is worth it and do you need the suspension at all is a separate question.

Comment: Does the difference in price and weight of the components translate to a difference in quality? (ps. don't know why you got down-voted... wasn't me).

Comment: Consider the difference in the gearing also, and what your preferences are.
Chainrings are 38-28T vs.  48-36-26T,
Cassettes  11-40T, 11-spd vs. 11-32T, 10-spd.
Personally, I would prefer the 3x10 over the 2x11 for commuting (just my preference though).

Comment: Good point. I'd also choose the 48 chainring.